# php trying to recieve unknow number of inputs

Tags: php, jquery, html, select, input

the application sort of a shopping cart.
 I load from an ajax source (any source would be the same xD) and unknown number of services (unknown cuz' they grow in number in the database).
they are represented by a check-box which  indicate if you want the service, then it displays 2 inputs one with the price disabled and the other to set quantity.

the problem is how do I send them all to php for process (total price calculation and database inserting).  I have used the input attribute name with brackets for multiple selects

```
<select name="something[]">...  ...</select>
```

I would like to know if there's a way to achieve something like that, but with inputs.
or maybe some fancy jquery plug-in in the kind of mooitems.-
here is the page to see my total fail attempt :(

http://www.micontrol.cl/~mvargas/wordpress/wp-transatacama/reservas-rapidas/form-reservas-pal.php

(you first have to select a viaje then a categoria, the services associated will display now, and finally adjust the qtty of adultos to be able to submit the form... sorry that flow was a requiriment : /).

please help me out with some guidance, something to read, anything :D
thx in advance.

Comment: yes, it works for input elements too. No changes needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not look at jquery serialize()?

http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

and then just iterate over $_POST[] or $_GET[] in your PHP depending on the method of your ajax call.

This may also be useful:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php#84813

Comment: let me check that maybe it'll would help.-
thought i was looking for a no JS answer, it seeems like impossible :/

Comment: You can send them however you want... You don't have to use js if you're actually submitting the form rather than using ajax. $_POST or $_GET will contain all of the successful controls with name attributes that were on the form when you submitted it. The second link shows you how to create variables using the keys and values from your array in php.

Comment: the problem that the services, does have the same name :/.
i was creating them dynamically from php, so my options were give them a name (same for all), not name them or dynamically create a numbered name that won't mean anything :/.
that's why i was asking there was a way to do something like [] in select multiple

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so if you have multiple items which you want to send to the server, you have to build your HTML to look something like the following (dynamic stuff are shown in square brackets []):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="service_[service_id]" value="[service_id]"/> [service_name]<br/>
<input type="text" value="[price]" disabled/>
<input type="text" name="quantity_[service_id]"/>
```

You have to build the names for the inputs composed of a prefix (like service or quantity) and a suffix which is the ID for that service, this way you will be able to check for them in the PHP.

Now in the PHP you could do something like this:

```
<?
    $prefix = "service_";
    foreach ( $_POST as $name => $value )
    {
        if ( substr( $name, 0, strlen( prefix ) ) == $prefix )
        {
            $serviceId = $value;
            $quantity  = $_POST[ "quantity_$serviceId" ];
        }
    }
?>
```

Here you can see i've created a loop over all of the POST data trying to find field names which start with the prefix service_ and once i find one, i know that its value is the service ID.  Then i can use the service ID in order to find the quantity_[service_id] field which was sent along with the selected service ID.

I hope this helps...

Comment: i think is a way of doing it, but is a little messy